# If a fully functional lab grown pancreas can exist, can it be used as a cure for type 2 diabetes?

Tags: human-biology, metabolism, human-anatomy, human-physiology

Is it approximately equivalent to say that if a fully functional lab grown pancreas exists, then a way to cure Type 2 diabetes could soon exist?

Recently I've already checked out that only the remission exists with some gastric surgery.

reference: 1)http://care.diabetesjournals.org/content/34/Supplement_2/S361

2) http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/733691(full access require membership)

Comment: Your question is not clear. I understand English is not your first language, but please try to rephrase your question to avoid being closed. I tried updating your title to capture what I *think* you are asking, but please address further...

Comment: @theforestecologist - is it looks good right now?

Comment: it is better, but still needs improvement. Please cite the source from which you "checked out" that remission exists. I'm also concerned that your question is too hypothetical (and therefore opinion based) and will likely be closed. Perhaps try to approach the question from a less hypothetical viewpoint.

Comment: You need to define what "remission" means. Millions of people live with well-controlled diabetes by monitoring their diet and using medications, obviously along with insulin supplementation. Also, please cite things that don't require "memberships" to read them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the consensus is that the underlying initial problem in t2dm is the development of insulin insensitivity in the presence of a normally functioning pancreas, then replacing that pancreas at a more advanced stage of the disease will not cause normalisation of glucose levels.

http://journal.diabetes.org/clinicaldiabetes/v18n22000/pg80.htm